# Programmatically Add ScriptManager

Tags: asp.net-ajax, sitecore, sitecore6, page-lifecycle

I'm attempting to add a ScriptManager control programmatically, but only if one doesn't exist on the page. I've found many examples for this that put the logic inside Page_Init, which makes sense (have since realized it *doesn't* make sense- see bottom edit), but I'm getting an exception before my Init method is ever hit.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page) == null)
    {
        ScriptManager sMgr = new ScriptManager();
        Page.Form.Controls.AddAt(0, sMgr);
    }
}
```

This makes me think Sitecore is getting in the way somehow. Has anyone successfully done this using Sitecore?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** The exception I'm receiving is as follows:
"The control with ID 'filtersUpdatePanel' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it."

**EDIT^2:** What was really going on here was that Page_Init is too late in the life cycle to attach a ScriptManager (in my case). With Init, all child events are fired first, then Page. The UpdatePanel's init didn't see a ScriptManager, so it threw an exception. Putting the ScriptManager logic in the UpdatePanel init solved the issue.

Comment: Could you post the exception?

Comment: There you go. That would help wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I usually do is create a PlaceHolder control in my base layout.
Then in my Page_Init (or in the Init of the control that requires the ScriptManager, like an UpdatePanel) I place the following code:

```
if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page) == null)
{
    ScriptManager scriptManager = new ScriptManager
    {
        ID = String.Concat("ScriptManager", DateTime.Now.Date.Ticks),
        EnablePartialRendering = true,
        ScriptMode = ScriptMode.Release
    };

    var placeholder = this.Page.FindControl("PlaceHolderScriptManager") as PlaceHolder;

    if (placeholder != null)
    {
        placeholder.Controls.Add(scriptManager);
    }
}
```

I have modified it a little without testing, but it should work fine.

Comment: See my edit for notes on this. Definitely helped me arrive at the answer! Thanks.